# Ability to insert information in more than one language

Tags: feature-request, jobs, localization

I have translated all my careers info to German because I primary target companies in Germany (or Swiss). But I would like to be able to apply to remote jobs in English speaking countries as well.

So I would like to be able to give the text in two languages, without having to put one underneath the other in the same field.